# Force Page Break with Syncfusion Essentials HTML to PDF Conversion

Tags: c#, syncfusion, html-to-pdf

I have been converting HTML to PDF using the `Syncfusion.HtmlConverter.HtmlToPdfConverter` class, which produces great results as long as you use the Webkit rendering engine, but I have not been able to get it to properly honor page breaks.  Syncfusion documents an older class, `HtmlConverter`, and suggests utilizing `<p style="page-break-before: always;">` which requires you to set the `AutoDetectPageBreak` property to `true`.

The problem is that the newer class does not contain this property.  Does anyone know the proper way to enforce page breaks using `HtmlToPdfConverter`?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the documentation is almost correct.  If you pass `<p style="page-break-before: always;">` as they suggest it will page break, but add a huge space after the break.  However if you use:

```
<p style="page-break-before: always;"></p>
```

It honors the break properly (and automatically) without the need for setting any properties on the conversion object.  This is as of version 14.2450.